# How to_date function with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YEAR')-365 FROM DUAL;
```

I get error

> 'invalide number'

Comment: Why are you converting date to string and only after that removing 365 from it? are you trying to get last years date? Try this `select TO_CHAR(sysdate - 365, 'YEAR') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: LoL you are trying to make minus from char value :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YEAR')-365 FROM DUAL;
```

doesn't work because you try to make an mathematical operation on string value `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YEAR')` which is not properly.
This will work

```
select EXTRACT(YEAR from sysdate)-365 FROM DUAL;
```

result

```
1650
```

but it doesn't make sense, so maybe you need this

```
select EXTRACT(YEAR from sysdate)-1 FROM DUAL;
```

result

```
2014
```

Comment: i want try this but not work : SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH,YEAR from sysdate) from dual; @Parado

Comment: @easy What do you expect with this query?

Answer (score 2):

See the result of TO_CHAR(sysdate-365, 'YEAR') and then think if you can cast this to a numeric value to be able to subtract 365.

```
'twenty fourteen' - 365
```

You probably want the previous year's date:

```
add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

Or if you need the year exactly 365 days before today:

```
extract(year from sysdate - 365)
```

Answer (score 0):

> TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YEAR')

It converts **DATE** into **string**. For date arithmetic, do the calculation on the date itself.

For example,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 365, 'YEAR') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I want to do subtraction system date with last years

Comment: @easy Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate. What is your desired output?